# How can an EC2 instance send a message to the AWS account holder?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to have a script that runs on my EC2 instances that sends email to the AWS account holder saying that the instance is still running.

How can I do this, without having the account holder provide their email?

- Is there any way for an EC2 instance to get the email address of the account holder, or at least to send an email to that person?
- Is there a way to set up some kind of alert that the instance can message?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get the email address of the AWS account holder. There are ways to get the account number/id but not the email.

For notification, look at [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/). You can send a notification (using Python/Boto) and have the account holder subscribe to the notifications. But your instance should have privileges to send SNS notifications.

Comment: Okay... Is there a way to send the account holder email?  Can the account holder set up an alert that gets sent to the account holder?